# 'if' does not work while iterating over array in 'foreach' javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, foreach

hello i created 3 arrays of data with xPos and yPos and with foreach started iterating over them

```
ctx.drawImage(Images['car1.png'],
            element.x,
            element.y,
            Images['car1.png'].width * SCALE,
            Images['car1.png'].height * SCALE);
element.y += SPEED * dt
if (PlayerYpos + Images['car3.png'].height * SCALE <= element.y) {
        CountEnd++;
        Entity.splice(index, 1)
        Entity.push({
            x: ~~(Math.random() * (canvas.width - Images['car1.png'].width - Images['car1.png'].width + 1)) + Images['car1.png'].width,
            y: ~~(Math.random() * (-700 - (-400) + 1)) + (-400)
        });
    }
```

It works fine, but when you create exactly the same code for an array created for, for example, Pit1.png, the last piece of code, which should push new data and then draw, does not work. I need to do it in this way for 3 pictures.

Perhaps I somehow make a mistake and I need to go in a completely different way, but I just started to delve into js and do not understand how to implement more functional. I just don't understand why I can't iterate over 3 arrays this way.

If someone does not understand what is happening by the paragraph with the code, I attach a link to hastebin with the full code. (pastebin doesn't open for some reason) https://hastebin.com/ehitewujix.js

I will also be very grateful for the notes on the code. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your code specifically, I believe the error is on lines 162 and 163, where Entity should be changed to Pit (Pit.splice, and Pit.push). Since, as I'm assuming you are forEach looping through Pit, and thereby wanting to modify the Pit array on those lines.

As a side however, I have found it less error prone/ easier to debug to use map() over forEach(). map() is marginally faster, and can do everything forEach() can do, but also returns results, which forEach does not (even though it will allow you to write a return into its callback function): https://morioh.com/p/b2d058745cb8

Comment: With a for loop, if with entity.push does not work either. With map (), I can't even imagine how to implement it, especially since I don't need a new array.

Comment: Just refreshed the page and saw the change.
With a for loop, if with entity.push does not work either. With map (), I can't even imagine how to implement it, especially since I don't need a new array. changing push helped, but at the moment the if triggered appears immediately pit and entity on PlayerYpos. The rest all worked

Comment: try just replacing forEach with map, see if that helps?

Comment: I rewrote it with map () and it worked. What should I do with the new array it creates?

Comment: haha, if you don't need the new array, just do nothing, otherwise assign the map to a variable.

Comment: Thank you so much!) I tried to add a rating to you, but they do not give me. sorry

Comment: I believe in your code, just do nothing. A map can also be used for side effects.